# File upload partial view in a popup asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, popup, partial-views

I have a file upload control in a partial view(_Managefiles),

```
@model Framework.Views.FileUpload
...
@{
var grid = new WebGrid(Model.UploadFileList, ...);}
<div id="gridContent">
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",...)

@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFiles", "PartialVw", FormMethod.Post,
  new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", Id = "frmManageFiles", UpdateTargetId = "Grd" }))
{
..
    <input id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile" type="file" />
    <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Upload File" onclick="javascript:StoreFormData()" />

}
```

this partial view is within a popup in a view(Expense.cshtml),

```
@model Framework.Views.Expenses
...
<div id="FileUploadModal" title="Upload File" style="display: none; overflow: auto;">
    @Html.Partial("../Shared/_ManageFiles", Framework.Views.FileUpload.Current)
</div>
```

on click of web grid row item link in the view, upload popup is displayed and file is uploaded on upload click button below is the controller event

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFiles(FormCollection form)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase File = Request.Files["uploadFile"];
        ... 

        File.SaveAs(FileUpload.Current.UploadFolderPath);           

        return View("../Expenses/Expenses", Expenses.Current);
    }
```

After each upload the popup disappears, it should persist after download. I'm thinking of using ViewData for this, is there any workaround for popup to persist?

I dont want to use any upload controls like uploadify, blueimp. I want to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a partial view i created a normal view for the upload control and on click of web grid row item link, a new window is opened and in this way only the newly opened window will be refreshed on upload

```
function UploadExpenseFile(e) {
    var l = (screen.width - 500) / 2;
    var t = (screen.height - 500) / 2;
    var f = window.open("@Url.Action("ManageFiles", "Tools", new { itemid = "_id" })".replace("_id",e), "_blank", 'resizable=0, height=500px,width=500px,top=' + t + ',left=' + l + 'w');
}
```